# Shell Text Processing Libraries

Tags: c, shell, serial-port, microcontroller

I need to write a very basic command interpreter on a micro controller that will communicate over a virtual serial port. Before I go ahead and write my own version of this, I was wondering if anyone knew of any libraries for very simple, shell-like text processing. I'd like the features that are standard in a shell, such as text received only being available after the user types in a new line, pressing backspace removes the last character in the queue rather than adding another char in the queue, stuff like that.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You want [GNU readline library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) maybe?

Comment: @pmg: GNU readline is likely to be *far* too memory-intensive for your garden variety microcontroller-based system.

Comment: +1 @Gilles. I didn't think of that. I agree it's likely to be too big :(

Comment: GNU readline is close to what I mean. I need something to simplify implementing a command line interface over a serial port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve a truly simple "shell" with line buffering (line buffering means processing only after an "enter" or '\n') in a microcontroller, i would do something like this (in the middle of the main loop:

```
char * p = my_read_buffer; //this is in the initialization, rather than the main loop

if (byte_from_my_uart_avaliable()) {
    *p = read_uart_byte();

    if (*p == '\n') {
        process_input(my_read_buffer);
        p = my_read_buffer; //reset the linebuffer
    }
    else 
        p++;
}
```

The secret then, would be the `process_input()` function, where you would parse the commands and its parameters, so you could call the appropriate functions to handle them.

This is just an idea far from finished, you would need to put a limit to the number of chars received before a `'\n'` to prevent overflow.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this. Looks like every other solution out there is too large for the problem. Maybe when I get around to it, I'll clean up my source and release a basic text front-end. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for a [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) interpreter. This is a large ecosystem, and you'll find many implementations that are intended to be used in firmware, such as [Open Firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Firmware)¹ implementations [OpenBIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBIOS). For example [Open Firmware](http://www.openfirmware.info/Open_Firmware)² is BSD-licensed and includes code for terminal access, which you may be able to reuse. I don't know how portable the Open Firmware code is, but if it doesn't suit you, I suggest searching for other Forth systems meeting your portability and licensing requirements and having a terminal access component.

¹  <sub>the specification</sub> 
²  <sub>the program</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ECMD](https://github.com/ethersex/ethersex/tree/master/protocols/ecmd), which is a part of the [Ethersex](http://www.ethersex.de/index.php/Ethersex/en) platform.

[ECMD Reference](http://www.ethersex.de/index.php/Ecmd_Reference).